# Time Machine reporting thousands of errors: setattrlist failed for path '/.MobileBackups/Computer/

Tags: backup, time-machine

For some reason, I can not longer complete a backup to a remote Time Machine server. In the error log, I see thousands of error messages. Here's generally what they look like:

> 2016-10-27 16:13:31.330679-0500  localhost mtmd[745]: (TimeMachine)
>   [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] -[FileAttrs
>   writeAttributesToItemAtPath:] setattrlist failed for path
>   '/.MobileBackups/Computer/2016-10-27-161316/Volume/Library/Preferences'
>   (errno 1)

The errors are slightly different only at the end (`/.MobileBackups/Computer...`)

Ultimately, the backup takes days before the connection to the server is reset for some reason and the backup fails to complete.

What are these errors and what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It may relate to this and/or help someone else figure out more about this but when I look at directories that are subject to the failure on my Mac, I see:

```
    sudo ls -al@ '/.MobileBackups/Computer/2016-11-05-233040/Volume/Library/'
    total 0
    d------r-x@ 4 root  wheel  136 Nov  5 23:33 .
        com.apple.backupdelta.MoveChecked     3 
        com.apple.s stem.Security    68
    drwxr-xr-x@ 5 root  wheel  170 Nov  5 23:30 ..
        com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID     36 
        com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID    20 
        com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID     36 
    d------r-x  5 root  wheel  170 Nov  5 23:32 Application Support
    d------r-x@ 4 root  wheel  136 Nov  5 23:33 Preferences
        com.apple.backupdelta.MoveChecked     3
```

I imagine most of these file attributes are related to Time Machine's local backup process, but I also notice that one of the attributes is `com.apple.s stem.Security` .. note the blank character in the `system` path component.  Could that be confusing things?  For example, if that attribute was *set* with that typo and later *cleared* (or attempted to be) with it spelled correctly, you would see an error like this.

Just guessing ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer yet either, but I'm basing my approach on bad content/permissions in the `.MobileBackups` subtree. Since these files store incremental backups in-between true Time Machine backups, I'm somewhat comfortable removing them and "starting fresh".

#### Viewing the logs:

Missing from the question is how to *view* the Time Machine logs. I installed a script in my `/usr/local/bin` directory, based on [the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1126990/how-to-view-time-machine-log-in-macos-sierra/1129106#1129106). However, a more straightforward command is simply:

```
log stream --style syslog --info --predicate 'processImagePath contains "backupd" and subsystem beginswith "com.apple.TimeMachine"'
```

#### Investigating Logged Errors

Inspecting the directories, there didn't seem to be much "off" about them (as @RamsayCons points out in his answer). Since I didn't care much about the most recent mobile backup, I decided to simply remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf /.MobileBackups/Computer/2016-12-16-112458
```

#### A few notes about this command:

- Remember that with `sudo` comes great power. Please be sure you understand exactly what you are doing before continuing.
- Similarly, `rm -rf` can cause great pain and anguish, so be sure that you are confident in what you are doing and have an exact directory specified.
- use the command `ls -la /.MobileBackups/Computer/` to list the contents of your existing Mobile Backups, so you can specify the correct

---

I am still waiting to see if this will resolve my problem, but so far I am seeing a new set of messages in the logs.

#### A few differences in my problem vs. that described:

- I am backing up to a locally mounted drive, however, the problem seems rooted in the files stored in the `/.MobileBackups/` directory, and not related to "where" the TimeMachine Backup disk is located
- My errors include a message that `volume Macintosh HD (/) is now in an emergency freespace condition`, and `low disk space thinning needed for volume Macintosh HD (/) with 7.7 <= 10.0 pct free space`, despite having `>40GB` out of `230GB` free.
- My Backup never "failed", but sat in the "Preparing backup ..." status in *System Preferences* for over 18 hours.

#### Update:

My Time Machine Backup eventually completed during the next scheduled hourly run... Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

The MobileBackups folder are used for the local Time Machine snapshots. I had the same problem after cloning (with CCC from Mike Bombich) a MacBook Pro.

Instead rm you can use:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
sudo tmutil enablelocal
```